# Saving figures in julia

Tags: image-processing, julia, winston

Two questions regarding Winston package

1. How do you change dimensions of an image using savefig?

I have a 256x320 matrix that i use to plot an image using Winston package with the imagesc() command and then when i try to save it using   savefig("picture.png","width","height") i get the same 512x512 pixels picture and i can't resize it, no matter how i change values : width, height.

2. Is it possible to export a FramedPlot chart to an image?

Regards

Mike

Answer (score 1):

To answer the first part, `savefig()` takes the variable number of positional arguments and named key value pairs, so the right way of calling your function is,

```
julia>savefig("name.png","width",10,"height",20)
```